# sybase privileges grant from one shcema to another

Tags: sybase

I have 2 schemas  `database1@server` and `database2@server`.

I want to know how to grant priveleges for database2 to read from database1.

example executing in database2:

```
select * from database1..table1
```

Comment: Just a note: Sybase uses the term Database instead of Schema to describe what you are talking about.

Comment: @MichaelGardner I edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make sure the user in `database2` is added to `database1` (`sp_adduser` or [sp_addalias](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1572/html/sprocs/X68891.htm)).

You can find your current user by doing `select user_name()` and get a list of users within a database by executing `sp_helpuser` in that database.

Assuming we have db_user1 and dbuser2, we would add the alias like this:

```
use database1
go
sp_addalias db_user2, dbuser1
go
```

From that point forward, when db_user2 is accessing database1, it will be with db_user1's credentials, rights and privileges.

If you add the user, instead of adding the alias, then you will have to [grant privileges](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/X69087.htm) for tables in the schema to the user (or group that the user is a member of).

Comment: exec sp_addalias database, database, @defdb=database .. like this ?

Comment: if i have database@server ... then.. sp_addalias database,dbo?

Comment: It gave me this error "No user with the specified name exists in the current database." but both databases exists... I am log in on db1 

use db1
go
sp_addalias db2, db1
go
is it correct ?

Comment: @Moudiz then you are not using the correct username in the database.  Try  `sp_helpuser` to get a list of users in the current database

Comment: Ahh okay I am was putting the name of database , I should add the user, then I got 2 users dbo with login name = sa  and userdb with empty login.. so i should add one of them right ?

Comment: @Moudiz Right, sp_addalias does not take a database name.  It is intended to execute within the current working database.  Although if your users are sa, there should be no need to do this.  Are these two databases on the same Sybase insance, or different instances?

Comment: as far as I know on the same instance , anyway I was doing test on my database to send it to client anyway as always thanks for your help.